# Xcode 5 will work in given configuration?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I am planning to have a Mac book pro 2008 model. 4 Gb RAM. 250 GB HD. Will xcode 5 will work fine in that model. Any idea, please suggest me.

Comment: You'd better extend your RAM to 8GB or above!

Comment: Is RAM extendable in that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its nothing to do with just your mac book model. If Your model supoorts OSX  10.8.4, xcode 5 will run smoothly. You can upgrade to mavrick as well. Check and try to upgrade you OS. But xcode 5 will work fine with OSX  10.8.4 and above.

You can check the [link](http://help.yoyogames.com/entries/26805787-Updating-Your-Mac-To-Use-Xcode-5) as well for upgradation.

Comment: I want to know the hang issue ?

Comment: Ok..thank...Have you experienced the same with 4 GB RAM?

Comment: Yeah I have 2 systems. One with 4 GB ram and another is with 8 GB. Definetly second one is more faster, but I have not feel any problem with the 4 GB one as well.